# find substring of any combination from string with any combination

Tags: regex, string, scala, replace, find

I am new to scala and regex.

I am facing problem replacing the word/words from string.

Consider I have following array of strings as addressArray from which I wants to find "east street"
what is the efficient way to find string from strings.

I want to remove every occurrence of **east street** from addressArray.

```
val addressArray = Array("shyam east street near corporation bank pune", 
                         "shyam eaststreet near corporation bank pune",
                         "shyameast street near corporation bank pune",
                         "shyam east streetnear corporation bank pune",
                         "shyameaststreet near corporation bank pune",
                         "shyam eaststreetnear corporation bank pune")

val stringtoFind = "east street"
```

Note : I do not want to replace white space with blank and concat string as I want rest of the string as is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove only those exact words you can do a replace, it's simpler than using regex:

```
addressArray.map(_.replace(stringtoFind, ""))
```

If you want more complex rules, for example match both "eaststreet" and "east street", you can use a regex like this:

```
val stringtoFind = """east\s*street""".r
addressArray.map(s => stringtoFind.replaceAllIn(s, ""))
```

Comment: I want to remove **east street** even if its with other string like **shyameast street**, **shyameaststreet**, **eaststreetnear** and so on.

Comment: @user1453370 see my updated answer. it should give the results expected